# Call a Python script with parameters from a Python script

Tags: python

Let's say I have a Python script named `script1.py` that has the following code:

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[1]
print("Bye", name)
```

And a second Python script `script2.py` that calls the first one:

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[1]
print("Hello", name)
import script1
```

How can I pass an argument from the second script to the first one, as in the given examples?

I'd like the output to look like this when I run my script from the terminal:

```
>> python script2.py Bob
Hello Bob
Bye Bob
```

Comment: I would use a callback function that returns your desired value

Comment: You're right vaultah. I hadn't realised that the parameters where share by both scripts. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options the way you're doing it (although your example does actually work right now because `sys.argv` is the same for both scripts but won't in the generic case where you want to pass generic arguments).

Use `os.system`

```
import os
os.system('python script1.py {}'.format(name))
```

Use `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script1.py', name])
```

A better way, IMO, would be to make script 1's logic into a function

```
# script1.py
import sys

def bye(name):
    print("Bye", name)

if __name__ == '__main__':   # will only run when script1.py is run directly
    bye(sys.argv[1])
```

and then in script2.py do

```
# script2.py
import sys
import script1

name = sys.argv[1]
print("Hello", name)
script1.bye(name)
```

Comment: The thing is that the script1.py logic is much complicate than the one shown here. That's why I didn't want to put the logic into a function, but you are right, that must be the best solution.
Thanks!

Comment: In general, don't write python like you'd write a bash script. Always put the logic in a `main` function or something and then use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` trick. If this worked, could you please accept the answer :)